# EasyPHP httpd.conf changes cannot be saved

Tags: apache, webserver, easyphp

I installed and used EasyPHP before it was working well. Now I try to install it in another desktop, but having problems saving httpd.conf. Every time I change anything in there and saved it, and if i reloaded the file in notepad, the changes are not taking effect.

Seems there is another program reverting it back to default values. I checked in the dash board, all services are not installed and none of them are running as it is first time install.

So how do I find out which program is reverting it? Or how do I make the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the culprit who is modifying the httpd.conf. It is the Dashboard page itself!
For my case, the desktop had setup a virtual network (for running Linux OS in VM), so the "Local Network" ip is always not getting the same as the IP set in my ethernet network.

In the dashboard index.php (C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Webserver-14.1b2\dashboard\index.php), there is a code to check both IP when it is not same, the original one is overwritten again. What i did to prevent the overwrite is to comment out the related codes:

```
// file_put_contents('..\binaries\httpserver\conf\httpd.conf', $httpdconf);
```

This of course only prevents the overwrites. The IP issue was solved by disabling the virtual network.